# Correct make command to include logging capabilities in AOSP

Tags: android, makefile, logcat, android-source

I added a `Log.i("IOBRIDGE", "iobridge open called")` in `open(String, int)` function of [IoBridge.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robovm/robovm-rt/1.2.0/libcore/io/IoBridge.java)

When I tried building with a simple `make` command, this error appeared:
`libcore/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/IoBridge.java:87: error: package android.util.Log does not exist`

I looked under android.util in `libcore/luni/src/main/java` and noticed the package did not contain Log.java. Eclipse was using Log.java found under `frameworks/base/core/java/android/util`

What is the correct build command to make sure the dependencies for Log is included?

Comment: Try taking it out entirely - most likely explanation is that your build procedure isn't quite right, and you will get the same error even without your  attempted extra logging.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I took out the logging statement/import statement and it built successfully. I am doing a simple "make" command with a -jN argument. What would be the better make command to make sure it recognizes the logging library?

Comment: What you claim you added should not be causing that error - you are going to have to post the actual code corresponding to the reported error line.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I updated the original answer with specifics